# How to find out whether audio playing is media or voice?

Tags: android, media-player, voice, soundpool, android-audiomanager

I am working on an android app that does audio routing to speaker/wired headset. Given that some audio is playing, is it possible to *programmatically* detect whether the audio playing is a song (media clip) or if it is voice from an established call, using java?

**EDIT**: I realized that I can solve my problem easily because, when I receive or make a call, only that *voice audio* can be heard. Is there any function which determines if I am on a call or not?

Comment: if you are recording call and if you want distinguish between them then it is easy to recognize with the saved file extension

Comment: No No.. I am listening to either a song or I am receiving a call. Now is it possible to programmatically find out whether the sound I am hearing is a song or is it voice from the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
public boolean isOnCall(Context context){
   AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
   if(manager.getMode()==AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL){
       return true;
   }
   else{
       return false;
   }
}
```

Add permission in manifest, too.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the simple solution. :)

Comment: Nice solution but how to change the mode? I have tried different solution but not worked